# Animate all recycler view items at once

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a recycler view with images. I am able to apply flip animation while clicking on an item. Now I want flip all images together when a count down timer runs out. How can I animate all the grid item once?

This is how my adapter's onBindViewHolder looks,

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        Picasso.with(context).load(imageList.get(position).getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(viewHolder.imageView);

        viewHolder.holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AnimatorSet setLeftOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
                        R.animator.crad_flip_right_out);
                AnimatorSet setLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
                        R.animator.card_flip_left_in);
                setLeftOut.setTarget(viewHolder.frontView);
                setLeftIn.setTarget(viewHolder.backView);
                setLeftOut.start();
                setLeftIn.start();
             }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

    Picasso.with(context).load(imageList.get(position).getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(viewHolder.imageView);

    viewHolder.holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            animateView(viewHolder);
        }
    });

}

public void animateViewsOfRecyclerView(){
    for(int i=0;i<recyclerviewAdapter.getCount();++i){
        animateView(recyclerview.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i));
    }
}
public void animateView(ViewHolder viewholder){
    AnimatorSet setLeftOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
            R.animator.crad_flip_right_out);
    AnimatorSet setLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
            R.animator.card_flip_left_in);
    setLeftOut.setTarget(viewHolder.frontView);
    setLeftIn.setTarget(viewHolder.backView);
    setLeftOut.start();
    setLeftIn.start();
}
```

Call the method "animateViewsOfRecyclerView()" whenever you need to animate all views.